# Indexing data from Microsoft Planetary Computer in Open Data Cube

Tags: open-data-cube

I would like to index into ODC some data from the [Sentinel-2](https://planetarycomputer.microsoft.com/dataset/sentinel-2-l2a) dataset available on Microsoft Planetary Computer (PC).

The main issue is with the PC's requirement of using tokens ([SAS](https://planetarycomputer.microsoft.com/docs/concepts/sas/)), which need to be appended to the URLs exposed by the STAC API, the ones then indexed in ODC. 
Those URLs will not have any token attached, resulting in 404 requests when trying to use `dc.load()`.

What is the recommended approach in this case? I have seen support in the [odc-stac](https://github.com/opendatacube/odc-tools) project, but I understand it doesn't index data in an ODC database, while I would like to have the data indexed. 
Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Planetary Computer support has been added in ODC through the `patch_url` parameter in `dc.load()` - [docs](https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/indexed-data/generate/datacube.Datacube.load.html#datacube.Datacube.load) - since v1.8.8, and with Dask support since v1.8.9.